# fopen is not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If a directory is not exist then I am creating a directory using "CreateDirectory" function.
Once a directory is created, I am trying to create "myfile.log" file using "fopen" function in the newly created folder. But somehow I am not able to create myfile.log file. It seems that my fopen function is not working. Please help me.

```
char *eptr;
FILE *errfile;
static char env[sizeof(NDGDBUG_FILE_EQUALS)+MAXPATHLEN];
f_GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, env);
strcat(env,"\\temp");
CreateDirectory(env,NULL);
eptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(env)+1);
strcat(env,"\\myfile.log");
eptr=env;
errfile = fopen(*eptr, "a");
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile - you're calling `fopen` with a single character instead of a string.

Comment: I doubt there is an environment where `\temp` is a valid directory

Comment: @hetepeperfan: On Windows, I think it refers to a directory named `temp` at the root of the current drive. `C:\temp` or `D:\temp` would be more explicit.

Comment: You must have gotten an error message from your compiler. Why didn't you show it to us? You say you are "not able" to create the file, but you don't tell us what happens when you try.

Comment: @KeithThompson I haven't used windows in years, how would CreateDirectory discriminate between `D:\temp` and `C:\temp`?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: I'm not a big Windows user myself, but I think it has a concept of a "current" drive, which is distinct from the "current" directory. In fact, there's a "current" directory for each drive. It's not pretty if you're used to the way Unix-like systems handle such things.

Comment: @hetepeperfan "\" indicates the root directory of a drive on which the current directory is.

Comment: Barring the programming errors, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA should be used for application data that is not user specific. By default, this location is read-only for normal (non-admin, non-power) Users. You should only be creating directories and altering the content at elevated app install time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(env)+1);
strcat(env,"\\sview.log");
eptr=env;
```

Why this? You have a memory leak, because you will lost memory created with the `malloc`. Just pass `env` to the `fopen`.

```
errfile = fopen(*eptr, "a");
```

Why `*eptr`? You want to pass the pointer to the string, and not the first character of the string.

So,

```
eptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(env)+1);
strcat(env,"\\sview.log");
eptr=env;
errfile = fopen(*eptr, "a");
```

should be

```
strcat(env,"\\sview.log");
errfile = fopen(env, "a");
```

If you want to store the path to the file, than you should copy the string into eptr:

```
strcat(env,"\\sview.log");
eptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(env)+1);
strcpy(eptr, env);
errfile = fopen(eprt, "a");
```

Comment: I need eptr in my further program.

Comment: @AparnaSavant If you need to save path to the file, then you need to copy the string, and not just to assign pointers. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

`*eptr` returns the first character, but `fopen` expects a string argument. You don't need to dereference on this case:

```
fopen(eptr, "a");
```